# GPO is applied but software is not installed

Tags: group-policy, deployment, msi

I'm trying to install Zimbra Connector for Outlook via Windows Group Policy on target computers. The problem is the policy is applied to the computers but software is not installed. I've checked the following:

- **GPRESULT /R** shows that the policy is applied to computer but the software is not installed.
- When I use another msi installer file (other then Zimbra Connector) it is installed as expected via the same GPO.

  - I'm able to install Zimbra Connector silently as user, that is: `msiexec /i \\path\installer.msi /quiet`

DC: SBS 2008

test computers: Win10 Pro x64, Win7 Pro x64.

**edit:**

I've enabled [application management debug logging](https://support.microsoft.com/pl-pl/help/249621/how-to-troubleshoot-software-installations-by-using-windows-applicatio) which gives me the error: **%1605**

I've also turned on *Windows Installer verbose logging* but it doesn't create a log file.

Comment: Is the policy setting "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" enabled?

Comment: @Greg Askew Yes, it is.

Comment: According to the ZCO admin guide, if you're not using a customized installer then each user needs to provide information during the ZCO install, which is probably why it's failing to install. It can't be installed non-interactively.

Comment: @joeqwerty But then how come I can install it without providing any information using msiexec command?

Comment: Enable group policy debug logging and check the gpsvc.log to see if it is actually performing the installation during computer startup. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2015/04/17/a-treatise-on-group-policy-troubleshootingnow-with-gpsvc-log-analysis/

Comment: 1605 only means "failed". You may want to enable Windows Installer verbose logging, and check the log file the installer creates in the temp directory.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/223300/how-to-enable-windows-installer-logging

Answer (score 0):

Check RSOP.msc at the client workstation, it should provide further information.

Does the computer account have access to the share where the installer is stored?
Are there any event log entries from the Windows Installer service that would indicate the installer process failed?

Have you customised the Zimbra Connector installer as per their docs? https://zimbra.github.io/zco-docs/8.8.8/ZCS_Connector_For_Outlook_Admin_Guide.pdf (older guide https://www.zimbra.com/docs/ne/5.0.19/zcs_connector_for_outlook_guide/)

Comment: Yes the computer account has access to the share where installer is stored. There are no event log entries indicated that something went wrong with the installation. I haven't customised the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, turns out it was permission on a file share we had relocated. The tech put "domain users" but not "domain computers".

Comment: OP said in a comment that the computer account has access to the share.